# List active sessions from tun interface

Tags: networking, centos, ip, netstat

I'm running `CentOS` and have a `tun` `interface` with `IP` `subnet` `10.0.0.0/24` attached for "users".

Is it possible to list current active sessions with `netstat`, `ss` or similar?

Ex. `netstat something`:

```
tun-mytest    10.0.2.32/32
tun-mytest    10.0.0.32/32
tun-mytest    10.0.11.1/32
```

Or some other way, and perhaps even have access to this sort of information directly from a database or similar?

Comment: Is this OpenVPN or what do you use to connect "users" to this interface?

Comment: No, it's a generic interface with custom code on it.

Comment: `lsof -i` maybe?